# Golang проблема с каналами

Tags: golang

Почему каналы не принимают новые сообщения? Только ЦПУ грузит на всю.
Мог бы кто нибудь мне объяснить в чем ошибка? Заранее Спасибо

СЕРВЕР

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"

    "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
)

var (
    newClientChan  chan *websocket.Conn
    newMessageChan chan []byte
)

func indexHandle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    indexFile, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("chat.html")
    w.Write(indexFile)
}

func wsHandler(conn *websocket.Conn) {

    newClientChan <- conn

    for {
        byf := make([]byte, 512)

        _, err := conn.Read(byf)
        if err != nil { continue }

        newMessageChan <- byf
    }
}

func main() {

    newClientChan = make(chan *websocket.Conn)
    newMessageChan = make(chan []byte)

    go chatServer()

    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandle)
    http.Handle("/ws", websocket.Handler(wsHandler))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func chatServer() {

    clients := make([]*websocket.Conn, 10)

    for {
        select {

            case client := <- newClientChan:
                clients = append(clients, client)

            case message := <- newMessageChan:
                fmt.Println(string(message))
                for _, client := range clients {
                    client.Write(message)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

КЛИЕНТ (chat.html)

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<button>send</button>

<div id="messages"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    const input = document.querySelector("#input");
    const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
    const messages = document.querySelector("#messages");

    const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws");

    ws.onmessage = (event)=> {
        messages.innerHTML += messages.innerHTML+event.data+"<br>";
    }

    ws.onopen = function(event) {

        btn.onclick = function() {
            if(!input.innerHTML) return;
            ws.send(input.innerHTML);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: На вскидку скорее всего `if err != nil { continue }` когда дойдёт до конца данных вы получаете `err==io.EOF.` на что ваш код начинает безконечный цикл т.к. `_, err := conn.Read(byf)` будет продолжать выдавать вам `err==io.EOF`.

Comment: Для вашей задачи в  `wsHandler()` вам следует использовать `websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &message)`  на пример https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/en/08.2.html